# File not updating latest version

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, versioning

I have an issue with a document library where a file is being uploaded as an updated version, however, the old version is still visible (image below).

What should normally happen is the newer and updated file should replace the old one, however, this is not the case.
[image: duplicate document library files]

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure the files has the **same name**. It only overwrites the file with the same name.

Similar issue: [SharePoint doesn’t overwrite a document with the same name, but creates duplicates](https://discoverlars.wordpress.com/2012/10/27/sharepoint-doesnt-overwrite-a-document-with-the-same-name-but-creates-duplicates/)

You can download a copy of the file from the SharePoint library, and then upload it to the library. See if it will overwrite the existing file with same name.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider checking:

1) Did You get a popup of notification about replacement ([screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/DC1flKrogV)) ?

2) Does Your current view shows items with OR without folders ([screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/A7FeYugAiCXu))? If Your view shows items without folders, this could be the problem ([example](https://www.screencast.com/t/CIY6DP9mOE)).

Comment: Hi Kristaps, to answet both your questions I dont receieve any messages like it shows on your screenshots, the file just simply uploads without overwriting the old one.

Comment: Hi @rashid - You answered the first question. Second one need investigation - please check current view configuration and look for "Folder" settings.